# SWT: Width of expandbar

Tags: java, eclipse, widget, swt, jface

at the moment I'm playing a little bit around with SWT and try to implement an expandbar:

```
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
            Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

            ExpandBar bar = new ExpandBar(container, SWT.V_SCROLL);

            Composite newConstraint = new Composite(bar, SWT.NONE);
            GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
            gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
            newConstraint.setLayout(gridLayout);

            Label sourcelbl = new Label(newConstraint, SWT.NONE);
            sourcelbl.setImage(getMyImage("source.png"));
            sourcelbl.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.CENTER, GridData.CENTER,
                    true, false));

            Label spacelbl = new Label(newConstraint, SWT.NONE);

            Label targetlbl = new Label(newConstraint, SWT.NONE);
            targetlbl.setImage(getMyImage("target.png"));
            targetlbl.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.CENTER, GridData.CENTER,
                    true, false));

            ListViewer lvSource = new ListViewer(newConstraint);
            lvSource.setContentProvider(new ConstraintDialogContentProvider());
            lvSource.setLabelProvider(new ConstraintDialogLabelProvider());
            lvSource.setInput(fm);

            Combo constrainType = new Combo(newConstraint, SWT.NONE);
            constrainType.setItems(new String[] { "require", "exclude" });
            constrainType.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.CENTER,
                    GridData.CENTER, true, false));

            ListViewer lvTarget = new ListViewer(newConstraint);
            lvTarget.setContentProvider(new ConstraintDialogContentProvider());
            lvTarget.setLabelProvider(new ConstraintDialogLabelProvider());
            lvTarget.setInput(fm);

            ExpandItem item0 = new ExpandItem(bar, SWT.NONE, 0);
            item0.setText("New Constraint");
            item0.setHeight(newConstraint.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
            item0.setControl(newConstraint);

omposite existingConstraints = new Composite(bar, SWT.NONE);
        gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
        existingConstraints.setLayout(gridLayout);

            ........

            ExpandItem item1 = new ExpandItem(bar, SWT.NONE, 1);
            item1.setText("Existing Constraints");
            item1.setHeight(existingConstraints.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT,
                    SWT.DEFAULT).y);
            item1.setControl(existingConstraints);

            item0.setExpanded(true);
            bar.setSpacing(8);

            return container;
        }
```

The problen then is the width, which doesn't seems to be computed:

[image]

Without the extendbar, everything works fine and the width is automatically computed:

[image]

How can I let the extendbar compute the width???

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 1):

The `ExpandBar` size computation only appears to take the size of the `ExpandItem` text in to account and ignores the size of the control in the item.

You would have to override the `ExpandBar.computeSize` method to change this (and also `ExpandBar.checkSubclass` to stop that rejecting your subclass).

Or you could just include spaces at the end of the text for the ExpandItems to fudge the calculated size.

Answer (score 0):

Based on greg-449's answer, I found another workaround, which is to set a widthHint for the ExpandBar:

```
    ExpandBar expandBar = new ExpandBar(this, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gridDataExpandBar = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);
    gridDataExpandBar.widthHint = 150;
```